# how to import LPCTSTR in cython?

Tags: c, cython

Can anyone tell me how can I import a typedef from standard C headers in cython?

I tried things such as:

Option #1:

```
cdef extern from *:
    r"""
    #include "xyz.h";
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    """
    ctypdef LPCTSTR pBuf
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    """
    ctypedef LPCTSTR pBuf
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cythonmodule.pyx:40:13: 'LPCTSTR' is not a type identifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Option #2:

```
cdef extern from "<windows.h>":
    ctypedef LPCTSTR xyz`
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...




cdef extern from "<windows.h>":
    ctypedef LPCTSTR xyz
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

package.pyx:33:13: 'LPCTSTR' is not a type identifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\x\project\cython\setup.py", line 35, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
  File "C:\Users\uesrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39  \lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1115, in  cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "D:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1238, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError:`
```

I would recommend if the option #1/inline C import is possible where then I could use LPCTSTR outside my inline C as below, otherwise any solution is much appreciated.

```
def heythere():
    cdef LPCTSTR abx = some()
```

Comment: `LPCTSTR` is either `LPCWSTR` aka `const wchar_t*` or `LPCSTR` aka `const char*` depending on whether the `_UNICODE` macro is defined or not during compilation.

Comment: @ikegami if I use ` cdef const wchar_t*`, I still get 'wchat_t' is not a type identifier

Comment: @ikegami, sorry, I meant 'wchar_t'